# it's not always possible to describe beauty

Tags: grammar, nouns, abstract-nouns

Does this sentence only contain Abstract nouns? I'm hoping for a yes.

"it's not always possible to describe beauty"

it is for an online quiz so I am hoping to get an idea

Comment: You've only got one, and I suppose it's abstract.

Comment: @Rob_Ster- ... and *existential it* ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence has two nouns: 'it' (to describe beauty), and 'beauty'.  Neither one can be 'touched', so they are both abstract.  (You can touch beautiful things, but not beauty itself.)

Comment: Of course, that assumes that you're of the religion that considers a pronoun to also be a noun.

Comment: I'm a 'grammatical scientist' - I test my theories.  I used the word 'noun' because 'topic' might not trigger the desired meaning.  Pronouns, nouns, determiners, infinitives and gerunds are all ways of pointing out topics, and those are either physical or abstract; and that matters grammatically because we base some elisions on that difference.